# How can I run Rake tasks more easily?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, rake, zsh

Running Rake tasks can be awkward.

The commands tend to be really long.

For example...

```
$ bundle exec rake some_project:clear_expired_sessions
```

Also, I may not always remember the exact name of some task I only use occasionally.

So I have to discover task's name first like this and then copy and paste it into the command line...

```
$ bundle exec rake -T some_project
```

I'm using Zsh on OS X with [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) and the Rake plugin.

It provides tab-completion of Rake tasks, but you still have to type "`bund exec rake`" the completions are really slow to load -- several seconds on my machine.

Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

You can always add an alias to your .bashrc or your .bash_profile to avoid `bundle exec rake` in the future.

`alias rake='bundle exec rake'`

Of course now `bundle exec` is implicated whenever you run `rake`, its up to you to decide if you want that.

or for project specific (lets say your project is rails_blog)

```
alias rkblog=railsblogtasks()
function railsblogtasks(){
  cd /path/to/blog/;
  bundle exec rake -T;
end

alias rkblogrun=runblogtask()
function runblogtask(){
  cd /path/to/blog/;
  bundle exec rake $1;
end
```

Now `$ rkblog` will show all your rails_blog tasks and `$ rkblogrun <task>` will run any task in your rails_blog project. This can of course be refactored and abstracted, but there is a general idea.

Answer (score 0):

One quick simplication:

```
task :example_alias => :environment do
  Rake::Task[some_project:clear_expired_sessions].invoke
end
```

Then you can simply do

```
  $ rake example_alias
```